# How can I repair broken off screws in tub overflow pipe?

Tags: bathtub, drain, overflow

Water has started leaking from my tubs overflow drain, down into a garage below.
My tub's overflow pipe is brass, and the two broken off screws in it are steel. Their stubs are about 1/4", weak, very rusted, and they ain't coming out backwards; (in my lifetime). The tub drain can have access through the wall, if its cut out. There may also be cut out access from the garage below.

I'm seeking to postpone paying hundreds to replace the overflow pipe through those ways. What's your opinion that the screws protrude through the back of the brass overflow elbow? But if they can't be screwed out through the back, does anyone know of a quickie repair "bar", that could be inserted in the overflow elbow? That way the overflow cover could be screwed on through that bar. The bar would need to have screw(s) holes threaded into it, that mate to a new overflow cover.

My internet searches have shown me a quickie fix that uses a plastic overflow tube inserted from the tub, down the overflow drain. Its glued on the overflow opening. I'm considering it. But I'd prefer a stronger, screw on "insert bar" device.

Comment: A clear photo would help. Could you upload one (or a few) to somewhere public and post a link here?

Comment: You said you can access the rear of the tub drain, so that is what I would do. That way you can hopefully see where the leak is coming from and replace the part. When done you can build a simple cover over the cut out area. I did this recently myself and built a cover out of 1/2" plywood (the drywall's thickness) and door/window frame molding screwed to the studs and painted the color of the wall. If I ever have another problem I can unscrew the cover for access.

Comment: THANKS, THAT WHAT I'VE DONE. I ALSO FOUND THAT THE 2 1/2" IRON SCREWS DID PASS THROUGH THE BACK OF THE ELBOW. BY ABOUT 1 1/4", AND THEY WERE SLIGHTLY CORRODED ONLY IMMEDIATELY WHERE THEY EMERGED FROM THE ELBOW. BUT (VERY DISAPPOINTINGLY) THEY WHERE TO CLOSE TO THE CORRESPONDINGLY INDENTED ELBOW HOUSING TO EASILY EVEN VICE GRIP THEM; LET ALONE DOUBLE NUT LOCK ONTO THEM! I COULDN'T EVEN DREMIL IN A SCREW SLOT WHILE STILL IN THE WALL. I JUST SCREWED OFF THE OVERFLOW PIPE, WITH ELBOW, AND REMOVED IT FROM WITHIN THE WALL. THEN I DREMILED IN THE SLOTS AND BACKED THE BROKEN SCREWS OUT. THANKS AGAIN.